# DataSourceUtils get proxy client information

Tags: spring, oracle, proxy, spring-jdbc

Connecting to the Oracle database through proxy user, is there a methods that can get me the real proxy client?

```
Connection jdbcConnection = DatasourceUtil.getPoolJdbcConnection();
```

Investigating `jdbcConnection.getMetaData().getCatalogs()` somehow I can find proxyClientName property, but not sure how can I actually get that property.